# The MongoDB sharded database 'partitioned' property remains false

Tags: mongodb, sharding, database-partitioning

The software version I am using is MongoDB 6.0.4 and Mongosh 1.8.0.Because I don't have many machines, I set up a sharded cluster on my local machine using different ports. The sharded cluster is configured as follows:

```
[direct: mongos] test> sh.status()
shardingVersion
{
  _id: 1,
  minCompatibleVersion: 5,
  currentVersion: 6,
  clusterId: ObjectId("643fd1088dc14852e495a094")
}
---
shards
[
  {
    _id: 'shard001',
    host: 'shard001/127.0.0.1:27117,127.0.0.1:27118,127.0.0.1:27119',
    state: 1,
    topologyTime: Timestamp({ t: 1681904960, i: 7 })
  },
  {
    _id: 'shard002',
    host: 'shard002/127.0.0.1:27217,127.0.0.1:27218,127.0.0.1:27219',
    state: 1,
    topologyTime: Timestamp({ t: 1681904968, i: 8 })
  },
  {
    _id: 'shard003',
    host: 'shard003/127.0.0.1:27317,127.0.0.1:27318,127.0.0.1:27319',
    state: 1,
    topologyTime: Timestamp({ t: 1681904975, i: 6 })
  }
]
```

I have created a database 'shardddb' and collections 'user' and 'users'. I have enabled sharding for the 'shardddb' database and performed sharding operations on the 'user' and 'users' collections. I have also inserted some data into the collections. The result is:

```js
{
    database: {
      _id: 'sharddb',
      primary: 'shard002',
      partitioned: false,
      version: {
        uuid: new UUID("e2603a9b-53e3-4ecd-8ef9-f35786431451"),
        timestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1682148090, i: 1 }),
        lastMod: 1
      }
    },
    collections: {
      'sharddb.user': {
        shardKey: { name: 1 },
        unique: false,
        balancing: true,
        chunkMetadata: [ { shard: 'shard002', nChunks: 1 } ],
        chunks: [
          { min: { name: MinKey() }, max: { name: MaxKey() }, 'on shard': 'shard002', 'last modified': Timestamp({ t: 1, i: 0 }) }
        ],
        tags: []
      },
      'sharddb.users': {
        shardKey: { name: 'hashed' },
        unique: false,
        balancing: true,
        chunkMetadata: [
          { shard: 'shard001', nChunks: 2 },
          { shard: 'shard002', nChunks: 2 },
          { shard: 'shard003', nChunks: 2 }
        ],
        chunks: [
          { min: { name: MinKey() }, max: { name: Long("-6148914691236517204") }, 'on shard': 'shard001', 'last modified': Timestamp({ t: 1, i: 0 }) },
          { min: { name: Long("-6148914691236517204") }, max: { name: Long("-3074457345618258602") }, 'on shard': 'shard001', 'last modified': Timestamp({ t: 1, i: 1 }) },
          { min: { name: Long("-3074457345618258602") }, max: { name: Long("0") }, 'on shard': 'shard002', 'last modified': Timestamp({ t: 1, i: 2 }) },
          { min: { name: Long("0") }, max: { name: Long("3074457345618258602") }, 'on shard': 'shard002', 'last modified': Timestamp({ t: 1, i: 3 }) },
          { min: { name: Long("3074457345618258602") }, max: { name: Long("6148914691236517204") }, 'on shard': 'shard003', 'last modified': Timestamp({ t: 1, i: 4 }) },
          { min: { name: Long("6148914691236517204") }, max: { name: MaxKey() }, 'on shard': 'shard003', 'last modified': Timestamp({ t: 1, i: 5 }) }
        ],
        tags: []
      }
    }
  }
```

However, the 'partitioned' property of 'shardddb' remains false, which I believe is abnormal. I hope someone can help me resolve this issue.

```js
[direct: mongos] config>  sh.enableSharding("sharddb");
{
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1683086356, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("0")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1683086356, i: 1 })
}
[direct: mongos] config> db.databases.find()
[
  {
    _id: 'sharddb',
    primary: 'shard002',
    partitioned: false,
    version: {
      uuid: new UUID("e2603a9b-53e3-4ecd-8ef9-f35786431451"),
      timestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1682148090, i: 1 }),
      lastMod: 1
    }
  },
```